# How can I set steps status using Cucumber and Extent Reports?

Tags: java, cucumber, report

I'm looking for a way to set status on test steps and then on Scenarios that will be displayed in an HTML report using extent report. I'm using now Cucumber Java TestNG & Extent Reports and I set the status using Assertions:

```
Assert.fail(msg)
```

the issue for assert is that he throws Assertion Exceptions and I didn't found a way to suppress exceptions so I would like to set the status using extent like:

```
extentTest.log(Status.FAIL, msg);
```

The issue here is that you need to create the feature/scenario/test and I didn't found any documentation on this.

Comment: Do you know how to use Cucumber ( Feature files ) and linking to the code for execution ???

Comment: Did that already and is working, i dont like the reporting part now.

Comment: Not sure what you like, check this tutorial might be helpful https://youtu.be/gidBcAz86Ww

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for some methods which would print messages based on your requirement in HTML Reports generated by Extent. If so, then you would need to customize or write down method as per your need. I am attaching screen shot of HTML also a piece of code to give you vision how shall you proceed.

[image]

[image]

Like below method would add screen and message as well based on test failure. You can simply change testReport.get().fail to pass or warning based on your need.

```
public static synchronized void logFailed(String message) {
try {
    testReport.get().fail("<details>" + "<summary>" + "<b>" + "<font color=" + "red>" + "Exception Occured : Click on the link to see message"
            + "</font>" + "</b >" + "</summary>" + "<br>" + "<h6>" + "<b>" + BasePage.returnLocator(message) +  "</b>"+ "</h6>" + "</br>" + message.replaceAll(",", "<br>")+"</details>"+" \n");
    addScreenShotsOnFailure();
}
catch(Exception e) {            
}   
}
```